# Display data from input fields in a table format

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, html-table

I'm trying to display the input data in a table format. The issue I'm having now is the display table will show the last data that was input.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
        <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value 1</th>
            <th>Value 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Topic1</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="Value_One"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="Value_Two"/></td>
    </tr>  
        <tr>
      <td>Topic2</td>
          <td><input type="text" class=" Value_One"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class=" Value_Two"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>    
      <th>Name</th>                                     
      <th>Value 1 </th>
      <th>Value 2</th>          
        </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
            <td class="name">Topic1 </td>
      <td class="value_1"></td>
      <td class="value_2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td class="name">Topic2</td>
      <td class="display_value_1"></td>
      <td class="display_value_2"></td>
      </tr>                         
  </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.Value_One').on('keyup change', function() {
    $('td.display_value_1').text($(this).val());
  });

  $('input.Value_Two').on('keyup change', function() {
    $('td.display_value_2').text($(this).val());
  });
});
```

EX 1 : 
Input Table

```
Name    Value 1   Value 2
Topic1  1         100
Topic2
```

Results Display Table

```
Name    Value 1   Value 2
Topic1  1         100
Topic2  1         100
```

EX 2 : 
Input Table

```
Name    Value 1   Value 2
Topic1  1         100
Topic2  2         200
```

Results Display Table

```
Name    Value 1   Value 2
Topic1  2         200
Topic2  2         200
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Name    Value 1   Value 2
Topic1  1         100
Topic2  2         200
```

JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/bhfhd4yr/18/

Comment: Looks like a few things are up with your class names. you have two listeners but four fields....

Comment: @deweyredman is right. you have to update your listeners ... [https://jsfiddle.net/bhfhd4yr/20/](https://jsfiddle.net/bhfhd4yr/20/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the same class to the inputs. Use the class to select all inputs (`$inputs`). Assign the same class to the target cells. Use the class to select all target cells (`$values`). Whenever an event handler of an input is fired, find the input's index in `$inputs` using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/). Use the index to assign the current input value to the corresponding table cell in `$values`:

```js
var $inputs = $('.input');
var $values = $('.value');

$inputs.on('keyup change', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var idx = $inputs.index($this);
  var value = $this.val();

  $values.eq(idx).text(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Topic1</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Topic2</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="input">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<br/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Value 1</th>
      <th>Value 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Topic1</td>
      <td class="value"></td>
      <td class="value"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Topic2</td>
      <td class="value"></td>
      <td class="value"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I ended up adding a second input table and result table. it worked perfectly. Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome :) If you've got many and / or large tables, instead of adding an event listener to each input, consider event delegation.

Answer (score 2):

You need more unique identifiers for your fields...check my updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bhfhd4yr/19/.

This can most certainly be cleaned up and optimized, but the issue is you were targeting two classes, while expecting four different fields to be unique.  I'm sure you could make a common listener if you restructured your code a bit.

Cleaned it up a bit more here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bhfhd4yr/21/
HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value 1</th>
            <th>Value 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Topic1</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="value_1"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="value_2"/></td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
      <td>Topic2</td>
      <td><input type="text" class="value_3"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="value_4"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


<br/>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>    
      <th>Name</th>                                     
      <th>Value 1 </th>
      <th>Value 2</th>          
    </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Topic1 </td>
      <td class="value_1"></td>
      <td class="value_2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Topic2</td>
      <td class="value_3"></td>
      <td class="value_4"></td>
      </tr>                         
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('keyup change', function() {
    $('td.'+$(this).attr("class")).text($(this).val());
  });
});
```